# Why can't you directly cast type in java?

Tags: java, android

In the code snippet below, why would lines 1 & 2 be fine and line 3 cause a compile error? Aren't the first two lines functionally equivalent to the third?

```
Loader loader = getLoaderManager().getLoader(0);
PatientLoader patientLoader = (PatientLoader) loader;
patientLoader = (PatientLoader) getLoaderManager().getLoader(0); // ERROR!
```

Throws this:

```
java: somepath/Patient.java:99: inconvertible types
found   : android.content.Loader<java.lang.Object>
required: com.example.package.PatientLoader
```

`PatientLoader` indirectly extends `Loader<>`.

I come from a C# background and in C# this would not be a problem, so maybe I'm missing something about the Java type system.

`PatientLoader` extends `AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>`. And anyone familiar w/ Android SDK would know `AsyncTaskLoader<>` extends `Loader<>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the placement of the parenthesis.
This problem has to do with Generics:

E.g. Compilation failure:

```
Loader<Object> loader = getLoaderManager().getLoader(0);
PatientLoader ch = (PatientLoader)loader; // Will show compile error (Cannot cast from Loader<Object> to PatienLoader)
```

But this will compile fine:

```
Loader<?> loader = getLoaderManager().getLoader(0);
PatientLoader ch = (PatientLoader)loader; // Compiles fine.
```

The difference is the <Object> generic versus the <?> generic declaration.

The problem is that getLoader(int) is defined to return a Loader<D>. This means that 'getLoaderManager().getLoader()' in the statement below gets interpreted as a Loader<Object> and not a Loader<?>.

```
PatientLoader ch = (PatientLoader)getLoaderManager().getLoader(0); // Compile error.
```

I think this is a 'bug' in the SDK. The method getLoader(int) should have been defined to return a Loader<?> and not a Loader<D>.

Comment: Is this a product of Java's type erasure?

Comment: No, it's not type erasure. Type erasure is the idea that the *runtime* cannot see the difference between an ArrayList<String> or an ArrayList<Integer> for example.